# Signing out user from Google+ API returns Error: $apply already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

Alright so just got signIn-functionality from the Google+-API working on my angularJs-webapp but i'm having trouble to get the signOut-functionality to work properly.

In one of my .html-files (the Nav-bar) i'm calling a function

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout()">SIGN OUT</a>
```

in the Nav-controller i'm calling the google-API sign out-function

```
 $scope.logout = function () {
        gapi.auth.signOut();
    };
```

Clicking the sign out-link results in the following error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
at angular.js:78
at beginPhase (angular.js:12720)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12509)
at $scope.signInCallback (auth.js:30)
at _.k.iu (cb=gapi.loaded_0:357)
at ix (cb=gapi.loaded_0:494)
at cb=gapi.loaded_0:495
at Zw (cb=gapi.loaded_0:487)
at jx (cb=gapi.loaded_0:495)
at Object.signOut (cb=gapi.loaded_0:505)
```

Don't really understand which "$apply" this may refer to? I'm I calling the signOuth-function in the right manner? Is it due to this script which i've placed in the index.html-file?

```
<script>
    // <![CDATA[
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
    // ]]>
</script>
```

EDIT:
This is my Auth.js-file, controller for the authentication. The code is just copied from [HERE](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/06/angularjs-google-sign-integration/)

```
    $scope.processAuth = function (authResult) {
        // Do a check if authentication has been successful.
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
            // Successful sign in.
            $scope.signedIn = true;

            //     ...
            // Do some work [1].
            //     ...
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
            // Error while signing in.
            $scope.signedIn = false;

            // Report error.
        }
    };

    // When callback is received, we need to process authentication.
    $scope.signInCallback = function (authResult) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.processAuth(authResult);
        });
    };
```

Comment: The error is coming from somewhere in your Angular app, not the Google+ API.  Check out [some other questions about this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%24apply+already+in+progress) to help debug it.

Comment: Show `$scope.signInCallback` function - it seems to be invoked and a call to `$scope.$apply` is initiated there

Comment: updated, The Auth.js-code is simply copied from a angularjs-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a setTimeout-function around the $apply-script in the signInCallback in my Auth-controller

```
  $scope.signInCallback = function (authResult) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.processAuth(authResult);
            });
        }, 0);
    };
```